# Backup and restore Zookeeper and Kafka data

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, tar

**zookeeper cluster**

```
sudo docker run -itd --name zookeeper-1 --restart=always   -v /data/zookeeper/zoo.cfg:/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg   -v /data/zookeeper/data:/bitnami  --network  sevenchats  -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes   -e ZOO_SERVER_ID=1   -e ZOO_SERVERS=0.0.0.0:2888:3888,ip2:2888:3888,ip3:2888:3888  -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888   -p 3888:3888 bitnami/zookeeper:3.8.0


sudo docker run -itd --name zookeeper-2 --restart=always    --network sevenchats  -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes   -e ZOO_SERVER_ID=2   -e ZOO_SERVERS=ip1:2888:3888,0.0.0.0:2888:3888,ip3:2888:3888  -v /data/zookeeper/zoo.cfg:/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg   -v /data/zookeeper/data:/bitnami   -p 2181:2181   -p 2888:2888   -p 3888:3888 bitnami/zookeeper:3.8.0


sudo docker run -itd --name zookeeper-3 --restart=always    --network  sevenchats  -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes   -e ZOO_SERVER_ID=3   -e ZOO_SERVERS=ip1:2888:3888,ip2:2888:3888,0.0.0.0:2888:3888  -v /data/zookeeper/zoo.cfg:/opt/bitnami/zookeeper/conf/zoo.cfg   -v /data/zookeeper/data:/bitnami  -p 2181:2181   -p 2888:2888   -p 3888:3888   bitnami/zookeeper:3.8.0
```

**kafka cluster**

```
sudo docker run -itd --name kafka-1 --network sevenchats -v /data/kafka/data:/bitnami –restart=always -v /data/kafka/server.properties:/bitnami/kafka/config/server.properties -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -p 9092:9092 bitnami/kafka:3.1.0

sudo docker run -itd --name kafka-2 --network sevenchats -v /data/kafka/data:/bitnami  --restart=always -v /data/kafka/server.properties:/bitnami/kafka/config/server.properties -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -p 9092:9092 bitnami/kafka:3.1.0

sudo docker run -itd --name kafka-3 --network sevenchats -v /data/kafka/data:/bitnami –restart=always -v /data/kafka/server.properties:/bitnami/kafka/config/server.properties -e KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=ip1:2181,ip2:2181,ip3:2181 -e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes -p 9092:9092 bitnami/kafka:3.1.0
```

after running these commands my cluster is working fine
I want to restore my Kafka data or topics to new cluster so using tar command I took the backup of the docker volumes on my host under /data/kafka/ folder

```
tar cvzf data_kafka1.tar.gz data
```

when I check the size of the folder on my existing cluster the /data/kafka folder is around 200MB
and when I copy my backup folder to new cluster and extract there using the command

```
tar xvzf data_kafka1.tar.gz
```

when I check the size of the data folder

```
du -hs data
```

it is 20GB on my new cluster

---

I want my backup size to be same on both the clusters

small difference is also fine but there is a huge difference in size

let me know what mistake am i doing?

Comment: Unrelated, but this isn't a healthy cluster setup since you cannot use the exact same property files and host volume mounts more than once between either Zookeeper or Kafka. In particular, Zookeeper and Kafka have unique IDs in each property file. (Also, as of Kafka 3.3.1, you don't even need Zookeeper)

Comment: The only way that I can visualize such a drastic multiplication effect, beyond the various RAID hidden duplication, is that *symlinks were followed and the data duplicated rather than referenced*.  Beyond that, I couldn't say.  But your command does not show usage of the **--dereference** option.  Unless, you are guessing at what command was actually used for each of creating or extracting the tar files.  What was the size of the compressed tar file: larger or smaller than the original data size?

Comment: HI @ eric the size of compressed file on the cluster where i took back up is less than the date folder

Comment: can you share me any link or document for healthy setup @OneCricketeer

Comment: Don't roll your own Docker cluster. Start here - https://strimzi.io And use solutions like Valero or k8s volume-snapshot